# I have a wandboard and I am trying to create a U-boot image so that ican use it in wandboard and i am using below steps?

Tags: c, linux, u-boot

I have downloaded Gcc compiler and uboot and saved them in a directory.  After that, I used the following commands:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/File address/Gcc_compiler/bin
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi-
export ARCH=arm
make wandboard_config
make
```

I am getting following error:

```
make arm-none-eabi-gcc not found
/bin/sh:arm-none-eabi-gcc not found
dirname:mising operand*
```

Please help I am new to this

Comment: `apt-get install gcc-arm-none-eabi`

Comment: I have the packages of gcc-arm-none-eabi but it is still not working